# Private node doesn't have ip address

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

I have an issue to setup ip address for node I run on my machine.

The command is

```
docker run -it -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 -v /home/user/Workspace/myether/datadir1:/root/datadir user/my-ether-node /bin/bash
```

I expect to see ip address, but id doesn't have it.

```
veth2c0a981 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6e:41:c9:a5:83:ac  
          inet6 addr: fe80::6c41:c9ff:fea5:83ac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:586 (586.0 B)  TX bytes:6320 (6.3 KB)
```

I will need on the second stage when I have to publish enode

I have connection to the network.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Instead of go through `ipconfig` I use `docker inspect` to find right ip address. With help of telnet tip address with port were verified.

Answer (score 0):

In docker command, you have to specify the RPC option to expose your IP to the outer world to connect

```
--rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

This command will allow you to communicate to the outer world using your machines IP address.